# JS reading variable from keyboard event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Welcome, I have a problem. I want to control object movement using the keyboard. The code that I have looks something like this

```
function ruszajLe(){

    $(document.body).on('keydown', function(x) {
        switch (x.which) {

            case 37:
                czyLe = true;
                facing = "LEWO";
                console.log('left arrow key pressed!');
                console.log('czyLe', czyLe, '  ', 'kierunek to ', facing);           
            break;
        }
    });
```

I also have a keyup handler that looks identical, but changes variable czyLe to false.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to read value from variables "czyLe" or "facing" and transfer them to another function?
2. Is this code executing asynchronously? If not, how can I make it execute that way?

Cheers

**Small edit**

I want to read my variable values inside of function like this, but `console.log` doesn't show any message:

```
function poruszanie(){
    if (czyLe === true) {
        console.log('porszanie dziala');
    }
}
```

Comment: as those two variables are global, they will be globally visible and therefore visible in the keyup handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See responses below to your two questions above:

1. Because you are not defining the `czyLe` and `facing` variables, they will be created as global variables. This means they will be accessible via any other keyboard events you have which want to get these values, same goes for any other logic wanting to access these values.
2. Your code here is nonblocking and therefore, asynchronous by community definition. Event listeners are only executed when the event is triggered. Your code will execute normally outside of the above code. Synchronous and blocking Javascript would mean your script would halt until someone pressed a key (which is not what happens). Technically you could call event listeners like yours achronological, but they are commonly referred to as asynchronous.

**Edit**

I just saw you updated your question. The problem is your global variables are only created/updated when your `keydown` event is fired. The fix here is to define them outside of the `ruszajLe` function, so put them at the very top of your Javascript outside of any created function.

```
var czyLe = false;
var facing = "";
```

Then your function will either return the default values above or the values set from within your event.

Comment: well i did what u wrote and this solution is not working. If i change value czyLe to true it is executing so i think variables are well declared. The problem is that i cant pass them to function. Here is link to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uecLc2on/, i dont know how to show console there

Comment: Your problem is your function gets called before any keypress event is fired. So it is always going to be false. You either need to call your function from within your key events or some kind of timer that loops and checks every X amount of time to see if anything has changed. Events are asynchronous, remember? So your function gets called because the event code gets off loaded to a browser task, only to be called when a key event is detected.

Comment: Yes thank you it worked. I wonder if i can put callback to other function to respond to keyboard events? Is this a good solution, or I should ask is it a dooable thing?

Comment: You can definitely specify a function as a callback function for an event. This is how I do it.

Comment: I'm trying to write this callback but i dont know how to. From turtorials i basicly know how callback works but i have no idea how to place it in my code. I dont know what arguments should i create and place them in function to make it work. If someone would place a piece of code or explain how do this i would be grateful

Comment: @KarolSz If you find a good book on javascript and go though it in order it will help with this kind of thing